# Unable to Parse reqular expression in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

This is my code,

```
String xyz = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"data\":[{\"RatingCount\":4}],         [{\"RatingCount\":1}], [{\"RatingCount\":1}]\"code\":1}";
    String pattern = ".*],\\s*\\[.*";//"(.*)(],\\s.*\\[)(.*)";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(xyz);
    boolean b = m1.matches();
    System.out.println(b);
```

I would like to replace pattern `'], ['` with `""`.

I used replaceAll but no luck

Comment: I tried with String s1=s.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[^,]*\\[)", "");

Comment: It is fixed. Check my [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35204301/5678086)

Comment: You need a JSON parser, not a regex...

Answer (score 0):

[Check it in working Fiddle](http://regexr.com/3cnqf)

Use the regex as below

```
String pattern = "\],[ ]*\[";
```

Answer (score 0):

xyz =xyz.replaceAll("]\s*,\s*\[", "],[");

This worked like charm and also this link helped me alot http://regexr.com/

Thank you for all your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

The output of this block is: `{"status":"ok","data":[{"RatingCount":4}{"RatingCount":1}{"RatingCount":1}]"code":1}`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"data\":[{\"RatingCount\":4}],         [{\"RatingCount\":1}], [{\"RatingCount\":1}]\"code\":1}";
    System.out.println(replace(str, "\\],\\s+\\["));
  }

  public static String replace(String str, String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    return matcher.replaceAll("");
  }
```